# How should I visualize a name mismatch for a SSL website?

Tags: security

I am writing custom security software and need to design a better method for a name mismatch... where the server certificate doesn't match the address in the URL.

How should I visualize this to the end user?

Comment: Can you give it some more context, some background, screen shots, wireframes etc.? What ideas do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

You could take inspiration from some web browsers: they show typically a green lock if the certificate is ok, or a red lock if the certificate is missing/invalid. Below is an example from Firefox.

[image: twitter]